# Why Can't I implement generic method in C#?

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to implement a simple generic method in c# that can convert from an NI `ComplexSingle` and NI `ComplexDouble` which are structs to a `Complex` as defined in `System.Numerics`, which is also a struct. Both
`ComplexSingle` and `ComplexDouble` have properties `Real` and `Imaginary` defined here:

```
    public double Real
    {
        get
        {
            return _privateBackingFieldForProperty_Real;
        }
        set
        {
            double privateBackingFieldForProperty_Real = _privateBackingFieldForProperty_Real;
            _privateBackingFieldForProperty_Real = value;
        }
    }

    public double Imaginary
    {
        get
        {
            return _privateBackingFieldForProperty_Imaginary;
        }
        set
        {
            double privateBackingFieldForProperty_Imaginary = _privateBackingFieldForProperty_Imaginary;
            _privateBackingFieldForProperty_Imaginary = value;
        }
    }
```

All I want to do is make a single function that can take in either a `ComplexSingle` array or `ComplexDouble` array and convert either one into a `Complex` array. I was hoping to do that by using a generic method as below. However, I soon realized that the `Real` and `Imaginary` properties could not be found because the generic passed in doesn't know about them. Then, I thought maybe I could use an interface, which I defined below that has the properties that are found in the actual struct. Now I am getting an error below at:

`Complex[] complexes = ComplexNItoComplex<ComplexDouble>(cd);`

that

[image]

Code is below:

```
using NationalInstruments;
using System;
using System.Numerics;

namespace ComplexStuff
{
    class ComplexMod
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Complex c1 = new Complex(4, 3);
            Complex c2 = new Complex(5, 4);
            Complex c3 = new Complex(6, 5);
            ComplexDouble cd1 = new ComplexDouble(4, 3);
            ComplexDouble cd2 = new ComplexDouble(4, 3);
            ComplexDouble cd3 = new ComplexDouble(4, 3);
            ComplexSingle cs1 = new ComplexSingle(7, 2);
            ComplexSingle cs2 = new ComplexSingle(7, 2);
            ComplexSingle cs3 = new ComplexSingle(7, 2);

            ComplexDouble[] cd = new ComplexDouble[]{
                cd1, cd2, cd3
            };
            Complex[] complexes = ComplexNItoComplex<ComplexDouble>(cd);


        }
        public interface IComplexNI
        {
            public double Real { get; set; }
            public double Imaginary { get; set; }
        }

        static Complex[] ComplexNItoComplex<T>(IList<T> NIComplex) where T : IComplexNI
        {
            Complex[] c = new Complex[NIComplex.Count];
            for (int i = 0; i < NIComplex.Count; i++)
            {
                c[i] = new Complex(NIComplex[i].Real, NIComplex[i].Imaginary);
            }
            return c;
        }
    }
}
```

Complex Double:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Security;
using NationalInstruments.Internal;
using NationalInstruments.Restricted;

namespace NationalInstruments
{
[Serializable]
[DebuggerDisplay("\\{{Real} + {Imaginary}i}")]
[TypeConverter(typeof(ComplexDoubleConverter))]
public struct ComplexDouble : IFormattable, ISerializable, IEquatable<ComplexDouble>
{
    private const string RealKey = "Real";

    private const string ImaginaryKey = "Imaginary";

    private double _privateBackingFieldForProperty_Real;

    private double _privateBackingFieldForProperty_Imaginary;

    public double Magnitude => Math.Sqrt(Real * Real + Imaginary * Imaginary);

    public double Phase => Math.Atan2(Imaginary, Real);

    public static ComplexDouble Zero => new ComplexDouble(0.0, 0.0);

    public ComplexDouble ComplexConjugate => new ComplexDouble(Real, 0.0 - Imaginary);

    public double Real
    {
        get
        {
            return _privateBackingFieldForProperty_Real;
        }
        set
        {
            double privateBackingFieldForProperty_Real = _privateBackingFieldForProperty_Real;
            _privateBackingFieldForProperty_Real = value;
        }
    }

    public double Imaginary
    {
        get
        {
            return _privateBackingFieldForProperty_Imaginary;
        }
        set
        {
            double privateBackingFieldForProperty_Imaginary = _privateBackingFieldForProperty_Imaginary;
            _privateBackingFieldForProperty_Imaginary = value;
        }
    }

    public ComplexDouble(double real, double imaginary)
    {
        this = default(ComplexDouble);
        Real = real;
        Imaginary = imaginary;
    }

    public static ComplexDouble FromPolar(double magnitude, double phase)
    {
        return new ComplexDouble(magnitude * Math.Cos(phase), magnitude * Math.Sin(phase));
    }

    public static ComplexDouble FromDouble(double real)
    {
        return new ComplexDouble(real, 0.0);
    }

    public static explicit operator ComplexDouble(double real)
    {
        return FromDouble(real);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return ToString(null, null);
    }

    public string ToString(string format)
    {
        return ToString(format, null);
    }

    public string ToString(IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        return ToString(null, formatProvider);
    }

    public string ToString(string format, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        string text = Real.ToString(format, formatProvider);
        string text2 = Math.Abs(Imaginary).ToString(format, formatProvider);
        NumberFormatInfo numberFormat = ComplexParser.GetNumberFormat(formatProvider);
        string text3 = (Real.IsNegativeZero() ? numberFormat.NegativeSign : null);
        string text4 = ((Imaginary < 0.0 || Imaginary.IsNegativeZero()) ? numberFormat.NegativeSign : numberFormat.PositiveSign);
        return string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}{1} {2} {3}i", text3, text, text4, text2);
    }

    public static ComplexDouble Parse(string input)
    {
        return Parse(input, null);
    }

    public static ComplexDouble Parse(string input, IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        if (input == null)
        {
            throw ExceptionBuilderBase.ArgumentNull("input");
        }

        if (!ComplexParser.AttemptParse(input, NumberStyles.Float | NumberStyles.AllowThousands, provider, ComplexParser.TryParseDouble, out var real, out var imaginary))
        {
            throw ExceptionBuilder.InvalidComplexDoubleFormat(input);
        }

        return new ComplexDouble(real, imaginary);
    }

    public static bool TryParse(string input, out ComplexDouble result)
    {
        return TryParse(input, null, out result);
    }

    public static bool TryParse(string input, IFormatProvider provider, out ComplexDouble result)
    {
        double real;
        double imaginary;
        bool result2 = ComplexParser.AttemptParse(input, NumberStyles.Float | NumberStyles.AllowThousands, provider, ComplexParser.TryParseDouble, out real, out imaginary);
        result = new ComplexDouble(real, imaginary);
        return result2;
    }

    public static ComplexDouble[] ComposeArray(double[] realData, double[] imaginaryData)
    {
        if (realData == null)
        {
            throw ExceptionBuilderBase.ArgumentNull("realData");
        }

        if (imaginaryData == null)
        {
            throw ExceptionBuilderBase.ArgumentNull("imaginaryData");
        }

        int num = realData.Length;
        if (num != imaginaryData.Length)
        {
            throw ExceptionBuilder.ArrayLengthsNotEqual("imaginaryData");
        }

        ComplexDouble[] array = new ComplexDouble[num];
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
            array[i] = new ComplexDouble(realData[i], imaginaryData[i]);
        }

        return array;
    }

    public static ComplexDouble[] ComposeArray(double[] realData, double[] imaginaryData, int startIndex, int length)
    {
        if (realData == null)
        {
            throw ExceptionBuilderBase.ArgumentNull("realData");
        }

        if (imaginaryData == null)
        {
            throw ExceptionBuilderBase.ArgumentNull("imaginaryData");
        }

        int num = realData.Length;
        if (num != imaginaryData.Length)
        {
            throw ExceptionBuilder.ArrayLengthsNotEqual("imaginaryData");
        }

        if (startIndex < realData.GetLowerBound(0) || startIndex >= num)
        {
            throw ExceptionBuilderBase.ArgumentOutOfRange("startIndex");
        }

        if (length < 0 || startIndex + length > num)
        {
            throw ExceptionBuilderBase.ArgumentOutOfRange("length");
        }

        ComplexDouble[] array = new ComplexDouble[length];
        int num2 = startIndex;
        int num3 = 0;
        while (num2 < startIndex + length)
        {
            array[num3] = new ComplexDouble(realData[num2], imaginaryData[num2]);
            num2++;
            num3++;
        }

        return array;
    }

    public static ComplexDouble[] ComposeArrayPolar(double[] magnitudes, double[] phases)
    {
        if (magnitudes == null)
        {
            throw ExceptionBuilderBase.ArgumentNull("magnitudes");
        }

        if (phases == null)
        {
            throw ExceptionBuilderBase.ArgumentNull("phases");
        }

        int num = magnitudes.Length;
        if (num != phases.Length)
        {
            throw ExceptionBuilder.ArrayLengthsNotEqual("phases");
        }

        ComplexDouble[] array = new ComplexDouble[num];
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
            array[i] = FromPolar(magnitudes[i], phases[i]);
        }

        return array;
    }

    public static ComplexDouble[] ComposeArrayPolar(double[] magnitudes, double[] phases, int startIndex, int length)
    {
        if (magnitudes == null)
        {
            throw ExceptionBuilderBase.ArgumentNull("magnitudes");
        }

        if (phases == null)
        {
            throw ExceptionBuilderBase.ArgumentNull("phases");
        }

        int num = magnitudes.Length;
        if (num != phases.Length)
        {
            throw ExceptionBuilder.ArrayLengthsNotEqual("phases");
        }

        if (startIndex < magnitudes.GetLowerBound(0) || startIndex >= num)
        {
            throw ExceptionBuilderBase.ArgumentOutOfRange("startIndex");
        }

        if (length < 0 || startIndex + length > num)
        {
            throw ExceptionBuilderBase.ArgumentOutOfRange("length");
        }
}
```

}

I know that the error only occurs if I have the real and imaginary properties in IComplexNI. I'm thinking I don't quite understand interfaces fully, since I was thinking that since I have `Real` and `Complex` defined in the interface, then the code would know to look for them when looking in the generic type. I guess that's wrong, though. I was guessing that you could reference the properties of objects or structs somehow in generic methods, but it sounds more complicated than what I was hoping..?

Comment: `ComplexDouble` - what is it?

Comment: It's just a struct, as mentioned above, which has a bunch of properties, but the most important that I mentioned that has a double `real` and double `imaginary` it takes in as a constructor, and stores them/can be retrieved.

Comment: You say `where T : IComplexNI`, I believe `ComplexDouble` implements `IComplexNI`?

Comment: No, it doesn't..That's probably where my issue arises... I might not need the interface. All I'm trying to do is create a generic where I can access Real and Imaginary properties. These two structs I intend them for is Complex Single and Complex Double, which both have the Real and Imaginary properties. Yet, It won't let me implement this as one method since it doesn't know Real and Imaginary from the generic at runtime.

Comment: Please post code, including error messages, as text, not as screenshots. Making it a [mre] also helps -- the full definition of `ComplexDouble` matters a lot here, but it's not provided.

Comment: I don't think that you need generics at all.  If you make ComplexNItoComplex a non-generic function and change the parameter from IList<T> to IReadOnlyList<ICompleseNI> things will likely work fine.  IReadOnlyList is covariant while IList is not.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/

Comment: I posted most of `ComplexDouble` above, even though, like I said, I don't think it will tell you more that you need. I did do ajz's idea above, but I'm getting a very similar issue:


Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'NationalInstruments.ComplexDouble[]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList<ComplexStuff.ComplexMod.IComplexNI>'

Comment: I guess my base question should have been "Is there a way to do this easily?' Also, what I said about ComplexDouble above is not true. It tells you that I am not implementing the IComplexNI, which I think was the original issue I was having. Although, not sure how to find a solution for what I need.

Comment: Can you show the code (at least the signature) of  the `ComplexNItoComplex` method?

Comment: It's in the second code snippet above.

Comment: ComplexDouble does not implement (inherit from) IComplexNI.  It must explicitly do this.  C# will not infer that ComplexDouble implements IComplexNI even though it implements the same methods/properties as the interface.  The inheritance needs to be explicit.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. I guess what I'm trying to implement still stands. Is there a way to do this if I can't implement that interface? Meaning getting properties of a struct through a generic method? Since I want to be able to pass either Complex Single or Complex Double which both have Real and Imaginary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't write a single method to convert both types. Both types have a `Real` and an `Imaginary` property each, but the types of these properties are different.

The `ComplexDouble` type has `Real` and `Imaginary` properties of type `double`.

The `ComplexSingle` type has `Real` and `Imaginary` properties of type `float`.

The easiest solution is to use method overloading: You can have two methods with the same name and different parameter types. The compiler will then choose the correct method automatically based on the type of argument you pass to them:

```
static Complex[] ComplexNItoComplex(IEnumerable<ComplexDouble> NIComplex)
{
    return (from c in NIComplex
           select new Complex(c.Real, c.Imaginary))
           .ToArray();
}

static Complex[] ComplexNItoComplex(IEnumerable<ComplexSingle> NIComplex)
{
    return (from c in NIComplex
            select new Complex(c.Real, c.Imaginary))
           .ToArray();
}
```

---

Sample usage:

```
ComplexDouble cd1 = new ComplexDouble(4, 3);
ComplexDouble cd2 = new ComplexDouble(4, 3);
ComplexDouble cd3 = new ComplexDouble(4, 3);
ComplexSingle cs1 = new ComplexSingle(7, 2);
ComplexSingle cs2 = new ComplexSingle(7, 2);
ComplexSingle cs3 = new ComplexSingle(7, 2);

ComplexDouble[] cd = new ComplexDouble[]{
    cd1, cd2, cd3
};
ComplexSingle[] cs = new ComplexSingle[]{
    cs1, cs2, cs3
};

Complex[] complexes1 = ComplexNItoComplex(cd);
Complex[] complexes2 = ComplexNItoComplex(cs);
```

Comment: That's what I initially had, then I thought I could be cool by only having one method. I guess generics aren't as amazing as I had originally thought, since they still limit you a lot in accessing class properties when the generic is a class?

Comment: Using a generic method would work if the types implemented a common interface. But they can't in this case because while the two structs have common properties, these properties have different types.